# Erro ao acessar variavel local em classe anônima

Tags: java, swing, escopo-de-variáveis

Por algum motivo o netbeans pede pra transformar a variável `i` em FINAL, porem se assim for, nao poderei edita-la.

Segue o erro:

> Erro: local variable i is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

A ideia é criar uma interface do jogo da velha, adicionando botoes num layout com 3 colunas e 3 linhas.

Na hora de adicionar `eventHandlers` para cada botão usando o ciclo FOR, nao consigo, pois o método da classe `ActionEvent` manda a variável ser FINAL. O que pode estar errado?

```
package TicTacToeProject;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * 
 * @author Igor
 */
public class PainelXD extends JPanel {
        private final JButton[] botoes;

    PainelXD(){

        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        botoes = new JButton[9];

        for (int i = 0; i <botoes.length; i++) {

            botoes[i] = new JButton("btn"+(i+1));

            botoes[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                     botoes[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("ticO.png"))); // erro aki local variable i is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                }


            });

            this.add(botoes[i]);

        }



    }

}
```

Novo codigo, erro consertado, mas agora ta dando `ArrayOutOfBounds` sinistro e incompreensivel na hora de usar o metodo da classe `ActionListener` nos botoes usando cliclo FOR. Por que está dando esse erro?

```
public class PainelXD extends JPanel {
         final JButton[] botoes;

         private int lol;

    PainelXD(){

        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        botoes = new JButton[9];

        for (lol = 0; lol <botoes.length; lol++) {

            botoes[lol] = new JButton("btn"+(lol+1));
            //System.out.println();

            botoes[lol].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                     botoes[lol].setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("ticO.png"))); // erro aki local variable i is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                }


            });

            this.add(botoes[lol]);

        }



    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
botoes[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        JButton btn = (JButton) ae.getSource();

        btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("ticO.png")));
    }
});
```

Ao invés de usar a referencia externa do botão a partir do indice local do laço dentro da classe anônima para adicionar uma imagem(e como pode ser [visto aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/192886/28595) isso não é possível), o código acima faz a mesma coisa, só que resgatando o botão através de seu *listener*. O método [`getSource()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource()) retorna o objeto de onde o evento foi disparado, neste caso, o próprio `JButton`.

Comment: sim, sua solução deu certo. mas n entendi absolutamente nada da sua soluçao. :DDD

Comment: @IgorAugusto editei com uma breve explicação.

Comment: sei q n é legal replicar com um "obrigado". mas obrigado! xd

Comment: @IgorAugusto disponha =)