# Por que não é possivel modificar variáveis locais quando acessadas dentro de classes anônimas?

Tags: java, escopo-de-variáveis

Quando se tenta acessar uma variável local a partir de um método de uma classe anônima em java, geralmente recebemos erro de sintaxe se tentarmos modificar seu conteúdo. Algumas IDE's sugerem que transformemos a variável em `final`, dessa forma, seu conteúdo se torna imutável, mas ai o erro muda, e passa a ser a tentativa de acesso a um conteúdo que não pode ser alterado.

Porém, se apenas lermos seu conteúdo, mesmo não modificando para `final`, nenhum erro é apresentado e o código funciona normalmente, com a cópia do conteúdo sendo feita sem problemas.

Mas quando se cria uma variável de classe e tenta acessar dentro da classe anônima, não só se pode ler seu conteúdo, mas também é permitido que ele seja alterado, como pode ser visto no exemplo abaixo:

```
public class AccessLevelVariableTest {

    private String oneVariable = "oneVariable";


    public void myMethod() {

        String localVariable = "localVariable";

        JButton btn = new JButton();

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

                oneVariable = localVariable; //isso é permitido
                System.out.println(localVariable); //isso é permitido
                localVariable = oneVariable; // isso ocorre erro de sinxate

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Se a variável local é enxergada pela classe anônima, acredito não ser um problema ligado apenas ao seu escopo, então qual o sentido de se restringir o acesso a uma variável local dessa forma, diferente da variável da classe? Que tipo de impacto permitir esse tipo de alteração poderia causar, para se ter essa restrição?

Comment: ah, acho seria bem mais simples perguntar porquê uma propriedade ou seja lá o que for, do tipo `protected` ou `private` não pode ser referenciada directamente.

Comment: @Edilson mas não é bem essa a minha dúvida, sobre modificadores de acesso eu já li aqui mesmo no site e entendi. A dúvida é sobre variáveis de escopo menor mesmo.

Comment: Variável local sendo acessada para leitura é permitido? Confesso que nunca reparei nisso. Achava que era proibido tanto leitura como escrita.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Respondendo brevemente – e eu não sou especialista em Java –, isso se deve à maneira como o Java lida com *closures*. O que o Java disponibiliza para a classe anônima não são as variáveis em si (ou seja, referências a determinados valores), mas sim seus valores. Assim, se a variável for alterada no escopo externo, isso não vai se refletir na classe anônima. Da mesma maneira, como se tem apenas um valor desvinculado da variável original, não é possível alterá-lo – se a linguagem permitisse, essa alteração só teria efeito dentro da classe anônima, e isso seria confuso.

Esse funcionamento *provavelmente* foi uma escolha deliberada, para evitar a complexidade adicional que isso exigiria do compilador. Já o C# funciona diferente (com sintaxe muito similar), porque fez uma escolha diferente.

**Fonte**: [*Why are only final variables accessible in anonymous class?*, resposta do Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4732617/825789)

Comment: Ou seja, não é *closure* :D

Comment: @bigown Pensei o mesmo. Mas o fato de o Skeet ter usado o termo me deixou na dúvida.

Comment: Há controvérsias sobre a definição exata, tem que diga que tem que ser a variável e tem quem diga que basta o estado dela.

Answer (score 3):

`localVariable` só existe durante a execução do método `myMethod()`. Como o objeto criado pode existir no escopo externo ao do método, a variável `localVariable` já não existirá mais.

Comment: Se ela não existe, como seu conteúdo é acessivel dentro da classe anônima? Veja o código da pergunta.

Comment: É mantido uma referência final. Como se tivesse se transformado em um atributo final dentro da classe anônima, tipo `new run() { final String localVariableInterno = localVariable; [...]`

Comment: Quem votou negativo pode explicar o porquê. O que é dito na resposta está errado?

Comment: Continuo não entendendo o raciocinio. de escopo da resposta. Se toda vez que a classe anônima é executada e o valor é usado, ele precisa existir, senão estaríamos trabalhando com um valor nulo.

Comment: Lembrando que a classe anônima é chamada no mesmo escopo da variavel local, ou seja, só será executada quando o mesmo método também for executado.

Comment: `Lembrando que a classe anônima é chamada no mesmo escopo da variavel local`, não, não é chamada nesse escopo. Ela é criada e passada adiante. Potencialmente (não é necessário _neste exemplo_ em específico, mas é possível no *caso geral*), ela pode ser executada em outra thread, ou pode ser executada em um executor em um thread pool. Você criou o objeto e passou adiante, o que acontece depois não está no contexto do método.

Comment: No caso do exemplo com Runnable, entendo que isso possa ocorrer, mas no caso de listener, o escopo é o mesmo, tanto que debbugando, o método fica travado até que a execução da classe anônima termine. Acho que o exemplo com Runnable acabou gerando essa confusão. Vou alterar o exemplo.

Comment: @ramaral, creio que quem tenha votado tenho sido o próprio diegofm, pois a resposta não havia sido suficiente. Foi tu mesmo, diegofm? Se não, se foi outra pessoa, pode confirmar o negativo?

Comment: No caso de qualquer variável você não tem o controle. Imagine uma `AbstractFactory`. O objeto por ela retornado vai ser consumido em um outro ponto fora do controle dela. Esse é o caso geral que falei

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado podes demonstrar isso na resposta? Eu realmente não estou conseguindo entender muito bem o raciocínio que você está seguindo.

Comment: @diegofm No caso do listener é igual, na altura em que o método da implementação(classe anónima) é chamado, o método que criou a classe já não está no escopo. Durante o escopo do método apenas foi criada a classe. Pense num listener para o click num botão.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Tente melhorar a respostas usando o conteúdo dos seus comentários.

Comment: @diegofm Você mesmo fala do caso de um atributo da classe, ele não necessita de ser final. Então, tudo tem haver com o escopo da variável.

Comment: @ramaral mas se fosse unicamente um problema de escopo, arrays e listas dariam o mesmo problema, mas quando a variavel local é lista, é permitido alterar seu conteudo normalmente.

Comment: @diegofm Tem a certeza?

Comment: @ramaral veja: https://ideone.com/KEQAtj

Comment: @diegofm Ela é final, o Java 8 infere isso. Por outro lado você não está a alterar a variável, tente fazer `localVariable = new  ArrayList<>();` dentro `actionPerformed()` e veja o erro.