# Variável local final em inner class no Java 8

Tags: java, variáveis, java-8, escopo-de-variáveis

Houve uma modificação entre as versões Java 7 e 8. Onde no Java 7 para uma variável local ser usada dentro de uma `inner class` deveria ser declarada `final`. Agora compilando com o Java 8, essa variável local não é mais obrigada ser declarada final.

Uma vez que as Inner Classes precisassem acessar as variáveis locais, elas teriam que ser copiadas para outra região de memória de modo a tornarem-se acessíveis por ela, o que poderia gerar várias cópias da mesma variável e correr o risco de ter dados inconsistentes. O que levou a essa mudança no Java 8, ou toda minha compreensão está equivocada?

Exemplo Java 7:

```java
public void msgAsync(final String msg){
   java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           jText.setText(msg);
       }
   });
}
```

Exemplo Java 8:

```java
public void msgAsync(String msg){
   java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           jText.setText(msg);
       }
   });
}
```

Ambos trechos de código compilam em suas respectivas versões, mas note o uso do modificador `final` sendo usado apenas no Java 7.

Comment: Relacionada:[Por que não é possivel modificar variáveis locais quando acessadas dentro de classes anônimas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192110/por-que-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-possivel-modificar-vari%C3%A1veis-locais-quando-acessadas-dentro-de-cla)

Comment: @PauloH.Hartmann até foi rápido, é que eu aviso todo fds pro pessoal ñ esquecer.

Comment: Você pode usar um lambda ao invés de uma classe anônima no Java 8 para deixar mais simples: `public void msgAsync(String msg) { java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> jText.setText(msg)); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Experimente fazer uma alteração em `msg` e veja se compila.

Java 8 resolveu inferir o `final` se não há alterações na variável, assim você não precisa ser explícito, mas no fundo mesmo em Java 8 `msg` é `final` e continua exigindo que seja, a diferença é que agora o compilador sabe se é mesmo sem estar escrito.

[A variável é efetivamente final](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html#accessing-members-of-an-enclosing-class).

Comment: Está correto, realmente quando modificada a variável na inner class o Java 8, acusa o erro, obrigado por esclarecer.