# Como uma annonymous innerclass seta uma variável privada de instância?

Tags: java, closures

Tendo em vista que o Java não possui de fato *closures*, mas emula o comportamento com uma técnica utilizando *inner classes*, o seguinte código:

```
class Test{
    private int myField;


    private void doSomething(){
        someInstance.setListener(new onClickListener(){
            @Override
            publicc void onClick(){
                myField = 3;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Irá, aproximadamente, virar:

```
class Test{
    private int myField;


    private void doSomething(){
        someInstance.setListener(new $AnonClass(this));
    }
}

class $AnonClass{
    Test test;

    public $AnonClass(Test test){
        this.test = test;
    }

    public void onClick(){
        //Como ele vai setar se a variável é privada???
        //Reflection???
        test.myField = 3;
    }
}
```

A minha dúvida é: Como o compilador(ou seja lá quem for) vai setar a variável privada?

Eu sei que é possível fazer isso com reflexão, mas não encontrei em nenhum lugar que de fato determinasse o que é feito nesse cenário.

E aproveitando o gancho, porque o Java não implementa logo de uma vez funções de primeira ordem e closures?

Comment: Relacionada [Qual a diferença entre classe interna, classe aninhada e classe anônima?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192104/28595)

Comment: Relacionada: [Por que não é possivel modificar variáveis locais quando acessadas dentro de classes anônimas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192110/28595)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois de conversar com alguns amigos e uma pesquisa mais profunda, descobri qual é o compartamento que acontece nesse caso. É algo meio obscuro e relativamente difícil de encontrar, então vou me esforçar para explicar.

O centro desse comportamento é um tipo de método, que é muito usado pelo Java, que é conhecido como *Synthetic Method*. De acordo com a especificação do Java, um elemento é sintético quando é produzido pelo compilador e não possúi um correspondente no código fonte, exceto os construtores padrão. Existem outros tipos de estruturas sintéticas, mas foquemos nos métodos sintéticos.

Então como esses tais métodos sintéticos resolvem o problema de acesso à uma variável privada de instância?

Bem, o compilador do java irá gerar métodos públicos para acessar TODAS as variáveis que são acessadas por uma innerclass. Vejamos o exemplo anterior.

```
class Test{
    private int myField;


    private void doSomething(){
        someInstance.setListener(new onClickListener(){
            @Override
            publicc void onClick(){
                myField = 3;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Temos uma classe anônima que está acessando uma variável privada de instância e que se transformará em algo do tipo:

```
class Test{
    private int myField;


    private void doSomething(){
        someInstance.setListener(new $AnonClass(this));
    }
}

class $AnonClass{
    Test test;

    public $AnonClass(Test test){
        this.test = test;
    }

    public void onClick(){
        //Por enquanto é mágica!
    }
}
```

E é ai que os métodos sintéticos entram. O compilador irá criar um método público na classe `Test` afim de dar acesso à variável desejada, e esse método é o famoso método sintético. Então, ficaria algo assim:

```
class Test{
    private int myField;


    private void doSomething(){
        someInstance.setListener(new $AnonClass(this));
    }

    public int access$0000(int a){
        this.myField = a;
    }
}

class $AnonClass{
    Test test;

    public $AnonClass(Test test){
        this.test = test;
    }

    public void onClick(){
        test.access$0000(3);
    }
}
```

Eu fiz um exemplo que dá pra ver esse tipo de método sendo criado.

Exemplo simples que mostra uma classe com um método Main acessando uma variável privada de uma innerclass.

```
public class SyntheticMethodTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test test = new Test(2);
        System.out.println(test.a);

        Class cls = test.getClass();
        for (Method field : cls.getDeclaredMethods()){
            System.out.println(field);
        }
    }

    static class Test{
        private int a;

        public Test(){

        }

        public Test(int a) {
            this.a = a;
        }

        public int getA() {
            return a;
        }

        public void setA(int a) {
            this.a = a;
        }
    }
}
```

O output é:

`2
static int SyntheticMethodTest$Test.access$000(SyntheticMethodTest$Test)
public void SyntheticMethodTest$Test.setA(int)
public int SyntheticMethodTest$Test.getA()`

E aí está o `static int SyntheticMethodTest$Test.access$000(SyntheticMethodTest$Test)`, que é o método sintético criado para acessar à variável `a`.

Se a linha `System.out.println(test.a);` for removida, o método não é criado.